# character set encoding in mutt

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, mutt

This question is increasingly esoteric, as we generally migrate away from text-based email reading. But often, I read and send email using mutt. When I copy something from a web page (usually encoded as utf-8), and then paste it into mutt, I get weird character encodings. Like, `\xe2\x80\x9cWhen push ..` (for a double quote).

I am using `Mutt 1.4.2.3i (2007-05-26)`;

My shell is `GNU bash, version 4.0.10(2)-release (i386-portbld-freebsd7.2)`;

My .bashrc file has `export LANG=en_CA.UTF-8`;

In my .muttrc, I specify `set charset = "en_ca.UTF-8"`;

Indeed, in mutt itself, if I type `:set &charset ?charset` I get back `charset="utf-8"`.

But I still don't get the result I'm looking for: when pasting text into an email, I get incorrect characters. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that mutt uses vi as its editor...

Comment: Yes, that's it. I had assumed that mutt was using vim! Thanks.